# Design layout EditText in Android

Tags: android

I want to design 2 EditText on background. I've tried. Please help.

[image: Example layout]

Comment: edittext on the bakground?what background?

Comment: your question is not clear.please post whatever you have tried and what you want.

Comment: can you briefly explain your query  we are unable to understand your query please use proper language so we can understand it thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to create some `editText` with your defined background

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbackgroundimage"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp" 
       >


        </EditText>
```

Just replace the `yourbackgroundimage` with your image here,Adjust attributes like height ,width here according to your needs.Make sure that image is present in one of the `drawable` folders present in `resources`